# Помогите решить проблему с Unity

Tags: unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил SDK, нужно указать путь , я не знаю к какой папке

Comment: К папке android-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Саму папку android-sdk нужно выбрать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]